# Magento 2: Spam Customer Accounts Created Automatically

Tags: magento2, security, captcha, security-scan-tool

I am using Magento 2.2.4 for my e-commerce website. From last few days, customer accounts creating automatically on my website without the proper information. I already installed Mageplaza Security plugin.

Please find attached screenshots for more info. How can I trace from where these logins are creating? These are creating only at once may be at the time of cron run.

[image]

[image: mag]

Comment: It's Chinese customers always!!! only google captcha can prevent it.

Comment: use recaptcha, use block ip etc

Answer (score 2):

As you're using an old version of Magento, you need to install the `MSP Recaptcha` extension (comes with latest Magento version) on your website.
You can use the MSP Recaptcha by running the following command in the terminal.

```
composer require msp/recaptcha:2.1.2
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope it helps!!!